# Kibana showing files with future date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

everyone

I have a fresh new log center with ELK Search and filebeat, when I access Kibana from the "Discover" menu the filebeat files are displayed with future dates (i.g. December 11th 2019, 11: 31: 55,000).

I already checked the timezone of the servers and they are all correct, when I changed the timezone in the kibana advanced settings, but without success.

```
#filebeat.yml

filebeat:
  prospectors:
    -
      paths:
        - /var/log/secure
        - /var/log/messages

      input_type: log

      document_type: syslog

  registry_file: /var/lib/filebeat/registry

output:
  logstash:
    hosts: ["elk_server_ip:5044"]
    bulk_max_size: 1024

    tls:
      certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"]

shipper:

logging:
  files:
    rotateeverybytes: 10485760 # = 10MB
```

and here is the logstash output

```
# 30-elasticsearch-output.conf

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: How is tha date in your logs and how are you parsing the date on logstash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only change that Kibana makes to the dates is to show it on the browser timezone per default instead of showing it in UTC, the problem could be on the way the date is being parsed on your logstash filter.